# Does the Puranas and Agamas give any remarks on what type of bodies should oversee temples?

Tags: temple

In India, to my understanding, temples are mostly overseen by Government agencies, and due to this, the culture surrounding the temple has changed a lot. See for example the Sabrimala case of the allowance of mensurating woman into that temple.

I came to wonder, does the Puranas and Agmas ever put remarks on what type of body should oversee temples and it's maintenance? Should it be autnomous?

Comment: no. It does not address. The GIta is a guide for spiritual attainment, not an organizational guide.

Comment: If Gita doesn't advocate/ say anything about temples, then why did hindu's create temples in the first place? @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Hindus do a 100 things daily that are not mentioned in Gita. Gita is not the only Hindu scripture. There are many others that Hindus follow. @Buraian

Comment: What scriptures deal with temple management and such @Rickross

Comment: Mostly Puranas and Agamas talk about things related to temples. @Buraian

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think the issue is clear enough. Could an explanation be given why it's not clear

Comment: That is just a bot. It automatically comments in the above manner if there is a close vote on the question. Right now I can see that there is one close vote on your question probably cast by the user Swami. You need not worry as the question is clear and it won't be closed. @Buraian